# Would it be an off topic question to ask some details about car crash test?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have seen some car crash test videos and have observed few common aspects in all and curious to know about it. I tried to Google but could not get a suitable result and hence thought of asking this here.  But before I do I thought of making sure that this not considered as off topic and checked this site's FAQ.  Unfortunately I could not still come to a conclusion with all these efforts and hence this question.

Comment: Every European crash test is available at http://www.euroncap.com/en, you may wish to check there to help refine any questions you have.

Answer (score 7):

When in doubt, you're always welcome to bring up this sort of question in the chat:

[The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop)

When it comes to questions, though, I try to filter my own questions on:

1. Is this question possible to answer at all?  For example, is it possible to put hands on data or an original source that can answer the question. Or is the issue too amorphous, insufficiently described, etc.
2. Is this a question with one (or a very small number close to one) answer?  If the issue is a debate spawner, it can be fun in the chat but won't be a good question for the site.

For your specific issue, I'd say visit the chat first. There's a good chance that you'll build up some interest in the topic and have some people primed when you actually post the question.